# Overlap elements based on position, arrange elements in spiral from outside in?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a grid of cubes with perspective, however when the cubes are on the bottom or the right the sides overlap with the other cube behind it. How can I make it so the cubes in the middle take precedence over those on the outside? This needs to be scaled up and down, so I can't just do a simple z-index on all of the elements, since the amount of cubes will change. here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/lucas-vanlaerhoven/pen/mdvpwLm)

HTML: (omitted many boxes for conciseness, will handle changing the amount based on screen size with JS in the future, check Codepen for example with more boxes)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.boxcontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100dvw;
  height: 100dvh;
  perspective: 300px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 5s;
}

.box * {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.box .top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px) translateY(-50px);
  background-color: blue;
}

.box .bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px) translateY(50px);
  background-color: green;
}

.box .left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50px) translateX(-50px);
  background-color: red;
}

.box .right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px) translateX(50px);
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box .front {
  background-color: gray;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: translateZ(30px);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxcontainer">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="front"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="front"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think this could be done by arranging the cubes in some sort of spiral from outside in, but I don't know how that could be accomplished. I've searched everywhere but cant seem to find anybody with the same problem. preferably id be using mostly plain CSS if possible.
worst case I could just set the perspective origin to someplace far in the bottom right, but I don't really like how that looks...

ps: This is my first post here, if I've done something wrong, please let me know so I don't do it again :)

Comment: I have managed to fix it by moving the `transform-style: preserve-3d;` to `.boxcontainer` instead